# passing file descriptors from the main process to its threads

Tags: pthreads, file-descriptor

I have a simple question regarding file descriptors passage from processes into their threads. I'm almost sure but need to a confirmation, if the files descriptors are treated as normal integers and thus can be passed through an array of integers for example to the process thread through the ***pthread_create()***  thread argument. Thanks

Comment: I wonder if there is anything that makes you doubt that. A simple test should have confirmed that this works. If you really have doubts, e.g. code that doesn't work where you suspect this to be the cause, that would make a much better question. Extract a minimal example to post here with a description of what happened and what you expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, file descriptors are just integers and so can be passed as function arguments like any other variable. They will still refer to the same files, because the open files are shared by all the threads in a process.

```
#include <pthread.h>

struct files {
  int  count;
  int* descriptors;
};

void* worker(void* p)
{
  struct files *f = (struct files*)p;
  // ...
}

int main(void)
{
  struct files f;
  f.count = 4;
  f.descriptors = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * f.count);
  f.descriptors[0] = open("...", O_RDONLY);
  // ...
  pthread_t t;
  pthread_create(&t, NULL, worker, &f);
  // ...
  pthread_join(t);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The rough definition of the term "process" could be "a memory space with at least one thread". In other words, all threads within the same process share a memory space.

Now, file descriptors are basically indices that reference objects within a table that belongs to the process. Since the objects belong to the process, and the threads operate inside the process, the threads can refer to these objects via their index ("file descriptor").